# Write file with <?php string in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file, templates

I need to create a file in CI usgin a template; the file created should starts with  <\?php string so I created a template like the following one:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Migration_<?php echo $class_name; ?> extends CI_Migration {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function up() {
        $this->myforge->add_field(array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE
            )
        ));
        $this->myforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
        $this->myforge->create_table('<?php echo $table_name; ?>');
    }

    public function down() {
        $this->myforge->drop_table('<?php echo $table_name; ?>');
    }

}
```

The $class_name and $table_name variables are parsed correctly by the Codeigniter controller but I'm not able to write correctly the first row.

The controller code to create the file is:

```
$my_migration = fopen($path, "w") or die("Unable to create migration file!");
$templatedata['table_name'] = $table_name;
$templatedata['class_name'] = $class_name;
$migration_template = $this->load->view('adm/migration/templates/create_table_template.tpl.php',$templatedata,TRUE);
fwrite($my_migration, $migration_template);
fclose($my_migration);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your view template file to the following should solve the issue.

```
<?php
echo 
"<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Migration_$class_name extends CI_Migration {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function up() {
        \$this->myforge->add_field(array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE
            )
        ));
        \$this->myforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
        \$this->myforge->create_table('$table_name');
    }

    public function down() {
        \$this->myforge->drop_table('$table_name');
    }

}
";
```

I have converted the whole content to a string, removed the `echo` statements within the content since the variable will be expanded by php, and finally escaped `$this` using a `\` since `$this` need not be expanded.